# RoR Rake - database error about a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, tzinfo

I am trying to create a db in my ror application with this command:

```
rake db:create
```

and I got this error:

```
Could not find tzinfo-0.3.26 in any of the sources
```

But when I did the "gem list" command, it turned out I had a newer version of this gem: tzinfo (0.3.27)

What can I do to sync up my gems to be more compatible?  Is this a common problem?  FYI I am using RVm to manage my gems.

I did do an rvm install tzinfo-0.3.26 command and got this output

```
jruby-1.6.1-tzinfo - #fetching 
jruby-1.6.1-tzinfo - #extracting jruby-bin-1.6.1 to /home/agenadinik/.rvm/src/jruby-1.6.1-tzinfo
mv: cannot move `/home/agenadinik/.rvm/src/jruby-1.6.1-tzinfo' to a subdirectory of itself, `/home/agenadinik/.rvm/src/jruby-1.6.1-tzinfo/jruby-1.6.1-tzinfo'
jruby-1.6.1-tzinfo - #extracted to /home/agenadinik/.rvm/src/jruby-1.6.1-tzinfo
Building Nailgun
jruby-1.6.1-tzinfo - #installing to /home/agenadinik/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.1-tzinfo
ERROR: Cannot switch to 1.6.2 for this interpreter.
jruby-1.6.1-tzinfo - #importing default gemsets (/home/agenadinik/.rvm/gemsets/)
Copying across included gems
Fetching: jruby-launcher-1.0.7-java.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed jruby-launcher-1.0.7-java
1 gem installed
```

Comment: Are you using Bundler? You could have 0.3.26 specified in your Gemfile.lock. If so, try running `bundle install`.

Comment: @matt I have not used bundler. Do I just type it like that "bundle install" - would it switch the gem to a correct version? Is bundle a gem or a command? Should I do "rvm bunle install" or something like that?

Comment: What version of Ruby on Rails are you using? Do you have the tzinfo gem defined in your environment.rb file or in the Gemfile?

Comment: @Pan ruby -v returned -->
jruby 1.6.1 (ruby-1.8.7-p330) (2011-04-12 85838f6) (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 1.6.0_24) [linux-i386-java]

Comment: @Pan the environment.rb file does not mention it. How do I look into the gemfile?  Which file is that? - Thanks!

Comment: No, which version of Ruby on Rails are you using, not which version of Ruby. If your environment.rb file does not have any gem definitions then check your Gemfile located at Gemfile and Gemfile.lock.

Comment: @Pan Actually, interesting thing... I got the same error message using "rails -v" - what do you think it could be?  And how to I check the rails version if that command didnt work?

Comment: What version of the Rails gem are you using? Check environment.rb and application.rb for a line like `RAILS_GEM_VERSION = "3.0.5"` what version of rails is that referring to? Do you have a Gemfile? Do you have gem definitions in environment.rb?

Comment: @Pan environment.rb does not have that line and application.rb does not have that line either. :) The GEMFILE does have this line: gem 'rails', '3.0.7'

Comment: Actually it got resolved by installing bundler like this "bundler install"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rvm install tzinfo-0.3.26
```

if thats what you typed in and executed. Should try running

```
rvm gem install --version '=0.3.26' tzinfo
```

that would install the 0.3.26 version of tzinfo

what you did first tells rvm to install a ruby runtime, not a gem.

Comment: This worked except you had a typo in your command with spacing after the equal sign. I can't edit it directly, but I submitted it for editing. - Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Although it still didn't fix my error.  This command: "gem list" still lists the .27 version of the gem.

Comment: @genadinik i just fixed the typo. when you executed the rvm gem install command, did it work without any errors? and whats the output of rvm list on your system? (may be you are using the system ruby, in that case rvm gem install will not install the gem to the system ruby).

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you're explicitly requiring 0.3.26 in your application. You could either change the requirement to "~>0.3.26" or install the required version with "gem install tzinfo -v 0.3.26".

Comment: I did do "rvm install tzinfo-0.3.26" and got the result that I am going to paste into my original question